# An unexpected error has occured. Related to installing conda pkgs

Tags: python, conda

I'm trying to get some conda packages installed in my environment. These packges are being pip installed by python. We're upgrading from py36 to py37 and the following output is occurring. Has anyone seen this before? What's the remedy for this?

> “An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above
>   report.", "", "Upload did not complete."], "stdout": "Collecting
>   package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done\nSolving
>   environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying
>   with flexible solve.\nSolving environment: ...working... failed with
>   repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata
>   source.\nCollecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working...
>   done\nSolving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen
>   solve. Retrying with flexible solve.\nSolving environment:
>   ...working... \nFound conflicts! Looking for incompatible
>   packages.\nThis can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to
>   abort.\nfailed", "stdout_lines": ["Collecting package metadata
>   (current_repodata.json): ...working... done", "Solving environment:
>   ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible
>   solve.", "Solving environment: ...working... failed with repodata from
>   current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.",
>   "Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done",
>   "Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve.
>   Retrying with flexible solve.", "Solving environment: ...working... ",
>   "Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.", "This can take
>   several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.", "failed"]}

Comment: What command(s) did you execute? What's already in the environment?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please ensure you have read [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and apply it to this and other questions in the future. As a first step, please format your question and make it as specific as possible. And don't forget to add precise reproduction steps.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times this problem happens when there is a conflict with the active python and the version of conda or the package you are trying to install. Most of the times downgrading python will help you. I usually downgrade python to version 3.6 which is more used. Then you need to downgrade conda to match the version od python. Here's the code:

```
conda install python=3.6
conda config --set allow_conda_downgrades true
conda install conda=4.6.14
```

Note: Currently there are many packages that are not compatible and updated for latest versions of python.